# Clean URLs mod_rewrite & wildcard subdomains

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I got this url

http://domain.com/blogs/directory-param

with this rule

RewriteBase /blogs/directory/
RewriteRule ^/blogs/directory-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /blogs/directory/index.php?cat=$1 [L]

so I get /blogs/directory/index.php?cat=param now my problem is the following:

I use wildcards subdomains so every *.domain.com is mapped to domain.com/blogs/ for example soeren.domain.com is mapped to domain.com/blogs and so on...

My problem now is I want a rule for soeren.domain.com/directory-param which points to domain.com/blogs/directory?index.php?cat=param

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me... what exactly do you want to know, what does not work ? Do you want to get rid of the sub-domain ?

Comment: Hi Archimedix I just edited the question above I hope it´s a bit clearer now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory(/|$)  
RewriteRule ^blogs/directory-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /directory/index.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

@Archimedix: Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well, to remove the sub-domain part, try an external redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

This, in addition to and before your existing rules.

Comment: Oh, I don´t want to remove the sub-domain part. I installed wildcard subdomains on my server. So the domain should still be: subdomain.domain.com/directory-param

Comment: I´m searching for something like this: http://soeren.tumblr.com/post/35400861477   in my case  http://soeren.tumblr.com/post-35400861477

Comment: I use a wildcard dns so everything *.domain.com is mapped to domain.com/blogs/

Comment: Which rule does this mapping from sub.domain.com to domain.com ? Just remove that one.

Comment: There is no rule for that I use wildcard dns subdomains